# Shading issues on bevels

Tags: uv, shaders

I am new to blender and basically i have a cube ans beveled the corners the auto shade smooth. The corner shading does not blend well with the cube and you can clearly see the line. See below.
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you share your .blend file using [Blender Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/), please? And it's usually better to post screenshots, and not photos of your screen, as they tend to be harder to interpret.

Comment: hey, sorry I was with my kid and had a picture on my phone. here is the blend file. thank you for looking at it.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=xo7omQKR" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/xo7omQKR/)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: No worries, and thank you. I actually see no problems with the rounded edges at all. I see some double geometry, but they are details (like a display or sticker, and some double geometry near the connectors near the back). Based on your photo, I think the issue has to do with visualization rather than your mesh. With 'Z' you can change your Shading: what does that do for you?

Comment: Hey Joachim, thank you for replying back. Its not a mesh issue exactly. My issue is with the shading. I have a matte grey finish on it. If you render it you can see a visible transition with the lights. I was wondering if there is a way to smooth it all as in one piece. Try to render it have the light on the side and you can clearly see the line and it gives different shades.

Comment: Also no visible problems. Have you tried rendering a different model, or importing the mesh into a new Blender file? Perhaps your configuration has a problem.